# Trying to use an api; bufferedinputstream causes a crash?

Tags: android, api, inputstream

I'm trying to use an API right now; first time using an API, and first time trying to do something on Android, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing.

First of all, I have this:

```
InputStream in = null;


        try {

            URL url = new URL(urlGetTerm);


            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());


        } catch (Exception e ) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            return lst;

        }
```

I figured out that it crashes at in = newBufferedInputStream(url.Connection.getInputStream());
after putting logs messages everywhere.

Why is this crashing? When I 'connect' to the API url using urlConnection, shouldn't getInputStream give me the json response? Going to the url at urlGetTerm correctly takes me to a page with the json response, so nothing is wrong with the actual url.

Log:

```
10-18 14:58:20.356  30708-30708/com.example.naomikoo.classalert E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.naomikoo.classalert/com.example.naomikoo.classalert.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
            at com.example.naomikoo.classalert.uwApi.getResult(uwApi.java:50)
            at com.example.naomikoo.classalert.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is line 50 of uwApi.java?

Comment: it's             System.out.println(e.getMessage());

Comment: Can you try replacing that line with: `e.printStackTrace()` and then posting the stack trace? I'm not sure, but it looks like the exception may be `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`. `e.getMessage()` is `null`.

You can't do network operations on the main thread.
When an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread,  the exception (`NetworkOnMainThreadException`) is thrown.

Use below code  to avoid this error else call your networking operations in thread or `AsyncTask`.

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

Comment: thanks! Sorry, I feel dumb now :( I don't know anything about exceptions. Do you know why getInputStream might be throwing one?

Comment: There are many exceptions that could raise. Please read it. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html
http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html